# xjc / jaxb2-commons interface binding issue, customization attached to the wrong place

Tags: xsd, maven-3, jaxb2, xjc, jaxb2-basics

I'm trying to add an interface using the jaxb2-basics artifact from the jaxb2_commons maven group.

My pom.xml contains the following dependencies

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-runtime</artifactId>
  <version>0.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```

and the plugin configuration looks like

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb22-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>jaxb-generate-messages-in</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <specVersion>2.2</specVersion>
          <schemaLanguage>XMLSCHEMA</schemaLanguage>
          <schemaDirectory>src/main/schema</schemaDirectory>
          <schemaIncludes>
            <include>MESSAGES-IN.xsd</include>
          </schemaIncludes>
          <bindingDirectory>src/main/binding</bindingDirectory>
          <bindingIncludes>
            <include>messages-in-binding.xjb</include>
          </bindingIncludes>
          <episodeFile>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/messages-in/META-INF/jaxb-messages-in.episode</episodeFile>
          <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/messages-in</generateDirectory>
          <extension>true</extension>
          <args>
            <arg>-Xinheritance</arg>
          </args>
          <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
              <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
              <version>0.6.4</version>
            </plugin>
          </plugins>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>jaxb-generate-messages-out</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <specVersion>2.2</specVersion>
          <schemaLanguage>XMLSCHEMA</schemaLanguage>
          <schemaDirectory>src/main/schema</schemaDirectory>
          <schemaIncludes>
            <include>MESSAGES-OUT.xsd</include>
          </schemaIncludes>
          <bindingDirectory>src/main/binding</bindingDirectory>
          <bindingIncludes>
            <include>messages-out-binding.xjb</include>
          </bindingIncludes>
          <episodeFile>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/messages-out/META-INF/jaxb-messages-out.episode</episodeFile>
          <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/messages-out</generateDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <verbose>true</verbose>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

As you can see from the above, there are two invocations of xjc, which both work.  Focusing on the first one, my bindings file

```
<jaxb:bindings
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
  xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
  xmlns:inheritance="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance"
  jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"
  version="1.0">
  <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../schema/MESSAGES-IN.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:globalBindings typesafeEnumMaxMembers="3000">
      <jaxb:serializable uid="1"/>
    </jaxb:globalBindings>
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
      <jaxb:package name="com.whatever.messages.request"/>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='YesOrNo']">
      <jaxb:class ref="com.whatever.messages.YesOrNo"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings noade="//xs:complexType[@name='someLogin']">
      <jaxb:class name="LoginRequest">
        <jaxb:javadoc><![CDATA[A Login request message.]]>
        </jaxb:javadoc>
      </jaxb:class>
    </jaxb:bindings>
  </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

works like a charm; but, when I attempt to add an interface to 'LoginRequest'...

```
   <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='someLogin']">
     <jaxb:class name="LoginRequest">
       <jaxb:javadoc><![CDATA[A Login request message.]]>
       </jaxb:javadoc>
     </jaxb:class>
     <inheritance:implements>com.whatever.messages.Request</inheritance:implements>
   </jaxb:bindings>
```

I receive the error message

```
 Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:/C:/Users/justme/Documents/NetBeansProjects/someproject/src/main/binding/messages-in-binding.xjb{19,42}].
 com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; systemId: file:/C:/Users/justme/Documents/NetBeansProjects/someproject/src/main/binding/messsages-in-binding.xjb; lineNumber: 19; columnNumber: 42; compiler was unable to honor this class customization. It is attached to a wrong place, or its inconsistent with other bindings.
```

which reports that the location was

```
 Error while generating code.Location [ file:/C:/Users/justme/Documents/NetBeansProjects/someproject/src/main/schema/MESSAGES-IN.xsd{106693,54}].
```

which happens to correspond to

```
 <xs:complexType name="someLogin" mixed="true">
   ...
 </xs:complexType>
```

Now, I've tried a second directive to bind the interface to the XSD element

```
 <xs:element name="someLogin" type="someLogin" substitutionGroup="externalMethod"/>
```

But I just get the same error message with the element's line number as the location.

Obviously one wants to attach an interface to a class, and all of the examples look pretty close to my bindings file, but something must be wrong.

My environment is

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 02:44:56-0600)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.2.1\java\maven
Java version: 1.7.0_07, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
```

Can someone explain why xjc believes the extension is operating on the wrong XSD type?

Comment: Does it work without jaxb:javadoc?

Answer (score 0):

In the construction

```
<jaxb:bindings 
  node="//Xs:complexType[@name='someLogin">
  ...
</jaxb:bindings>
```

the `node` attribute is expected to be an XPath expression.  (Or so it says at [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html)).  Try adding the closing square bracket to make it one, and see if that helps.

Comment: actually, the closing bracket is in the original source.  As I stripped out the incriminating bits (changing it to someLogin) I messed up the XPath directive.  I'll update it in the question.

Comment: Still, thank you very much for the pointer.  If only it were that simple.